# How can I update the underlying data during this Entity Framework 6.x migration?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

## Overview

I'm trying to update an existing application from the original design (simplified for clarity):

```
// Current design

class Audit {
  int Number { get; set; }
  Person Supervisor { get; set; }
}

class Person {
  int ID { get; set; }
  string Name { get; set; }
}
```

To the following design that uses a separate Supervisor class:

```
// Improved design

class Audit {
  int Number { get; set; }
  Supervisor Supervisor { get; set; }
}

class Supervisor {
  int ID { get; set; }
  Person Person { get; set; }
  // ...other supervisor properties
}

class Person {
  int ID { get; set; }
  string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The goal is to keep `Supervisor` related properties separate from the `Person` class and corresponding database table.

## Question

**How can I update the underlying data** so that

- a new Supervisor row is created for each existing unique Supervisor_ID in the Audit table,
- the new Supervisor's Person_ID points to the correct person,
- the Audit's Supervisor_ID is updated to the ID of the new Supervisor.

Is this something that can be done in the EF migration's `Up()` function (or perhaps elsewhere) during the migration, or do I need to tackle this separately using handcrafted SQL scripts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As soon as I realized it didn't have to be exclusively (1) DbContext or (2) standalone SQL script, I came up with this solution that runs the SQL during the migration:

```
public override void Up()
{
    CreateTable(
        "dbo.Supervisor",
        c => new
        {
            ID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
            Active = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
            Person_ID = c.Int(nullable: false),
        })
        .PrimaryKey(t => t.ID)
        .ForeignKey("dbo.Person", t => t.Person_ID, cascadeDelete: true)
        .Index(t => t.Person_ID);

    // for each unique Supervisor_ID in audits create a new supervisor with that Person_ID
    Sql("INSERT INTO Supervisor(Person_ID, Active) SELECT DISTINCT Supervisor_ID, 1 FROM Audit;");

    DropForeignKey("dbo.Audit", "Supervisor_ID", "dbo.Person");

    // for each audit update Supervisor_ID to the ID of the supervisor with that Person_ID
    Sql("UPDATE Audit SET Audit.Supervisor_ID = Supervisor.ID FROM Audit JOIN Supervisor ON Audit.Supervisor_ID = Supervisor.Person_ID;");

    AddForeignKey("dbo.Audit", "Supervisor_ID", "dbo.Supervisor");
}
```

*I'd still be interested to know if there are any other ways besides this approach.*

### UPDATE 2021-04-26

<s>It looks like the migration does not detect the change in FK so this answer is incomplete.</s> Updated answer to include manual change of foreign keys.